# Read Only Role Permission in Magento Admin Panel

Tags: magento, permissions

I just want to ask on how do I create a role permission in Magento which requires read only access.
The role permission is specifically designed for customer service representaives, and I want to grant them role without modifying the backend side.

Any suggestions or solutions in creating read only permissions.

Role: Customer Service
Permission: Read only access on Sales Order Tab

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a feature of Magento, and would require a core file to be overwritten. There are safe ways to do this, and most likely it'd be just this one file:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
```

And a simple way to accomplish that without introducing an entire module structure would be to copy it to your local codepool and modify it there:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
```

Local codepool is loaded before core, and in Magento class names match locations in the file system, so if this file exists in local then Magento won't bother looking for it in core.

Comment: I tried to override the core file of Action.php, most of the submit functions are working which says "Access Denied". 

The thing is other functions are still editable like:
resending email messages,
bulk status updates, and so on.

The read-only function is not fully integrated. 
I think 60% of the function only works. =)

Any suggestions.

Thanks,